# Speeding up this SQL query

Tags: sql, performance

I have the following (fairly legacy, did this a year or two ago) SQL query. The webpage the SQL is on (used on an SqlDataSource/GridView in ASP.NET) is very slow, and I've pinpointed the slowness to this query - seemingly because of the sub select. I've tried using joins to hopefully speed it up but I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

I won't put the whole query here, simply because I work on a machine with no internet access so I won't be able to copy and paste, and most of it is just selecting from the main table.

```
SELECT ..., 
       CASE 
         WHEN di.Total = di.Delivered THEN 'Received' 
         ELSE 'Not Received' END AS 'Status',
       ...
FROM Deliveries AS d 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT Delivery, 
                COUNT(*) AS Total, 
                COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 2 THEN 1 END) AS Delivered 
         FROM DeliveryItems 
         GROUP BY Delivery
  ) AS di ON d.ID = di.Delivery
```

Any tips?

Comment: Can you add the execution plan from Query Analyser? That usually tells you what step is causing the slowdown.

Comment: You have correct indexes on DeliveryItems.Delivery and Deliveries.ID?

Comment: Retagged - the ASP.Net stuff isn't relevent, this is pure SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Delivery, 
       COUNT(*) AS Total, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 2 THEN 1 END) AS Delivered 
FROM DeliveryItems 
GROUP BY Delivery
```

This part could be improved by ditching that CASE statement. Maybe try joining twice, once against the total count and once against the filtered count.

```
SELECT ..., 
       CASE 
         WHEN d2.Total = d1.Delivered THEN 'Received' 
         ELSE 'Not Received' END AS 'Status',
       ...
FROM Deliveries AS d 

LEFT OUTER JOIN (

SELECT Delivery,
       COUNT(*) AS Delivered
FROM DeliveryItems
WHERE Status = 2
GROUP BY Delivery ) d1 ON d.Id = d1.Delivery

LEFT OUTER JOIN (

SELECT Delivery,
       COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM DeliveryItems
GROUP BY Delivery ) d2 ON d.ID = d2.Delivery
```